# What is wrong with my balance method in my BinarySearchTree? (Java)

Tags: java, arrays, recursion, binary-search-tree, nodes

I created a method that is suppose to balance a BinarySearchTree.

The instructions were that the balance method should update the tree so that it is balanced, meaning that the largest difference between subtree heights is no more than 1.

With the following process:

• Get an array of sorted values in the tree (we have a method that can do this)

• Assign the tree's root to the result of the buildTreeUtil helper method (described below)

• Call assignFirst to update the tree's "first" attribute

The buildTreeUtil(E[], int, int, BSTNode parent) helper method rebuilds the tree using a sorted list of values. Since it has this sorted list, it doesn't have to search for where to insert new values, so it doesn't (and shouldn't) call the add method. Instead, it selectively grabs values from the sorted list of values when adding new nodes. It's algorithm is as follows:

• If the "start" parameter is greater than the "end" parameter, the recursion should stop

• Create a new node storing the middle element in the list

• Assign the new node's left reference to a recursive call using the left half of the list

• Assign the new node's right reference to a recursive call using the right half of the list

Here is the following code:

```
public void balance()
{
    this.root = buildTreeUtil(toArray(), 0, size(), first);
    assignFirst();
}

private BSTNode<E> buildTreeUtil(E[] values, int start, int end, BSTNode<E> parent)
{
    if(start > end)
    {
        return null;
    }
    int mid = (start + end)/2;
    BSTNode<E> node = new BSTNode<E>(values[mid]);

    node.left = buildTreeUtil(values, start, mid - 1, parent.left);

    node.right = buildTreeUtil(values, mid + 1, end, parent.right);

    return node;
}

private void assignFirst()
{
    if (root.left != null)
    {
        first.left = first;
    }
    else
        {
        first = root;
    }
}
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public E[] toArray()
{
    ArrayList<E> aList = new ArrayList<E>();
    E[] arr = (E[]) new Comparable[this.numElements];
    toArray(this.root, aList);
    return aList.toArray(arr);
}

private void toArray(BSTNode<E> node, List<E> aList)
{
    if (node != null)
    {
        toArray(node.left, aList);
        aList.add(node.data);
        toArray(node.right, aList);
    }
}
```

This is just the rest of my code cut short so there is some valuable background information.

```
public class BinarySearchTree<E extends Comparable<E>>
{
private BSTNode<E> root; // root of overall tree
private int numElements;
private BSTNode<E> first;
// post: constructs an empty search tree
public BinarySearchTree()
{
    this.root = null;
    this.numElements = 0;
}
public class Iterator
{
    private BSTNode<E> currentNode;

    public Iterator()
    {
        currentNode = first;
    }

    public boolean hasNext()
    {
        return currentNode != null;
    }

    public E next()
    {
        E value = currentNode.data;
        currentNode = currentNode.next;
        return value;
    }
}
private static class BSTNode<E>
{
    public E data;
    public BSTNode<E> left;
    public BSTNode<E> right;
    public BSTNode<E> parent;
    public BSTNode<E> next;

    public BSTNode(E data)
    {
        this(data, null, null, null, null);
    }

    public BSTNode(E data, BSTNode<E> left, BSTNode<E> right, BSTNode<E> parent, BSTNode<E> next)
    {
        this.data = data;
        this.left = left;
        this.right = right;
        this.parent = parent;
        this.next = next;
    }
  }
}
```

I'm not sure where the error occurs or if I'm assigning the incorrect values inside the parameters for buildTreeUtil.

Comment: What is the error ? we need o know what's wrong in order to address it.   For example, Are you getting an exception? If so, what type and what line?   Or is it just not the expected result?  If so, how is it different from what you were expecting?  (some minimal test data and actual results ? )

Comment: I'm not sure to be honest, because when I run my tests, it doesn't give me a clear answer, however I'm assuming it could be what I am passing through the parameters..

Comment: Then it's time to start working on a [mcve] first. It's an important second step in debugging that almost always leads to people finding the actual error all on their own.